# how can I specify the checkpoint directory in ray.tune.run_experiments

Tags: python, ray

ray.tune.run_experiments checkpoints the model at some path like "/ray_results/test/DDPG_VAV-v0_0_2019-04-17_21-43-43ak0121vf/", it is too lengthy, how can I change this checkpoint path

```
    run_experiments({
        'test': {
            "resources_per_trial": resource,
            'run': 'DDPG',
            'env': 'Pendulum-v0',
            'config': {
                "input_evaluation": [],
                'exploration_final_eps': 0,
                'exploration_fraction': 0},
            'checkpoint_at_end': True,
            'checkpoint_freq': 500,
            'stop': {"training_iteration": 5000}}
    })
```

I hope I can set it like "~/ray_results/test/DDPG_2019-04-17/"

Comment: I would consider setting `trial_name_creator` (see https://ray.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tune-usage.html#launching-an-experiment)

Comment: but it's not useful, if I set trial_name_creator to return 'incremental', the path becomes '~/ray_results/DDPG/incremental_2019-04-24_13-15-438p6ypg31'